# How to get all the workbooks in project in Tableau

Tags: python, tableau-api

I am using TableauServerClient.
My code :

```
all_workbooks,pagination_item=server.workbook.get()
for wb in all_workbooks:
 print(wb.name)
```

It prints all the workbooks in server(From all projects).I need to print only workbooks present in particular Project(i know the Project name and id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workbooks object contains project information according to the [docs](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#workbooks).

Something like this should work:

```
all_workbooks,pagination_item=server.workbook.get()
for wb in all_workbooks:
    if wb.project_name == "YOUR PROJECT NAME":
        print(wb.name)
```